# Has anyone died from tampered candy at Halloween?

Tags: children, safety

Year after year parents are bombarded with all of the risks of trick or treating.  Razor blades in apples, poisoned candy, etc.  Even the [CDC](http://www.cdc.gov/family/halloween/) warns against eating anything homemade or before a parent has inspected it.

With all the hype of what *could*  happen, have there been any confirmed cases of a child being harmed by tampered candy, poisoned food, etc.?

Note, I'm only referring to the candy/treat itself, not the risk of kidnapping, getting lost, etc.

Comment: It's still important to be aware of the possibility though (and inspect, particularly, your favourite candies since they always seem to be the most suspicious).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

According to [this research paper](http://www.thefolklorist.com/pdf/Best_1985.pdf), only 76 incidents have been documented as 'Halloween sadism' at the time of its writing (1985).  Of those, two have resulted in death; however neither case turned out to be caused by candy received from trick-or-treating.

> In 1970, five-year-old
>   Kevin Toston died after eating heroin supposedly hidden in his Halloween candy. While this story
>   received considerable publicity, newspapers gave less coverage to the follow-up report that Kevin
>   had found the heroin in his uncle’s home, not his treats *(San Francisco Chronicle, 1970).*

The second case:

> In 1974, eight-year-old Timothy O’Bryan died after eating Halloween candy
>   contaminated with cyanide. Investigators concluded that his father had contaminated the treat *(Grider. Sylvia, 1982 “The razor blades in the apple syndrome.”).*

So in both cases, the deaths resulted from family member negligence or harm, and not some mysterious stranger handing out halloween death.  I haven't found anything more recent yet.

From the synopsis at the beginning of the paper:

> This paper examines the widespread belief that anonymous sadists give children
>   dangerous treats on Halloween.  A review of news stories about Halloween sadism from
>   1958 to 1983 suggests that the threat has been greatly exaggerated. Halloween sadism
>   can be viewed as an urban legend, which emerged during the early 1970s to give
>   expression to growing fears about the safety of children, the danger of crime, and other
>   sources of social strain.

Comment: +1, suggest changing opening line to note that neither death was from candy received via trick-or-treating.

Comment: @Russel good point, will do.

Comment: +1 for this answer.  I note that it is also consistent with what a police officer said on CBC Radio One (Canada's government funded national radio station) in an interview a few years ago about the number of cases with people being poised by tainted candy handed out anonymously on Old Hallow's Eve' -- his point was that he wasn't aware of any cases in North America involving strangers, just a few where relatives were involved in the poisoning.